# How to get multiple column data in a comma separated string?

Tags: csv, sql-server-2000

I am getting data like

```
Result
------
 10
 23 
 21
```

But i want to get data in the following format.

```
Result
------
10, 23, 21
```

How to get that in a Query?
Thanks in advance for any help **:)**

Comment: Sorry i forgot to tell that i want to do it without using any stored procedure.

Comment: How to do this for multiple columns like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037777/send-dbmail-from-sql-server-2000-with-tabular-structured-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way,
There is a student table having studentName column with datatype as nvarchar(50) then following query will give you student names as comma separated values,

```
DECLARE @VALUES NVARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @VALUES = COALESCE(@VALUES + ',','') + CAST(STUDENTNAME AS NVARCHAR(50)) FROM STUDENT
SELECT @VALUES
```

Answer (score 3):

Sample code that doesn't use stored procedure :) ...

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
-- Check Table Column
SELECT Name
FROM HumanResources.Shift
GO
-- Get CSV values
SELECT SUBSTRING(
(SELECT ',' + s.Name
FROM HumanResources.Shift s
ORDER BY s.Name
FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) AS CSV
GO
```

More about it here:

[SQL SERVER – Comma Separated Values (CSV) from Table Column](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/25/sql-server-comma-separated-values-csv-from-table-column/)

Edit:

For **SQL-Server 2000**, take a look here:

[How to Format Query Result as Comma Separated Values (CSV)](http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/03/15/how-to-format-query-result-as-comma-separated-values-csv/)

Comment: I think XML PATH is not supported in SQL Server 2000 :(

Comment: You're right. It's not supported. http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1077. For SQL-Server 2000, see the edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check out:
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-coalesce-to-build-comma-delimited-string