# How do I group two column but return all three column value from single table

Tags: sql

I have single table name test with field1, field2 and field3

```
Field1     Field2    Field3
a             x        10
a             x        20 
b             g        30 
b             g        40  
c             u        50
c             u        60
```

I want to see group Field1, Field2, (NOT Field3) and return all value Field3

Comment: Can you give example what you require?

Comment: [format](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-to-use-formatting-in-comments) question properly...

Comment: could you also post output that you want in question too?? I have no clue what you want... `I want to see group Field1, Field2,( NOT Field3) and return all value Field3 ??????????`

Comment: Can we write sql to return all value in field3 having group by field1 and field2. I hope make more sense to you

Comment: output please in question?? we can do but we are not getting what you want...

Comment: Please state what you think the results should be if you ran the query on the sample data you provided.

Comment: Ok like this Select field1, field2, field3 from tableone group by field1, field2 and it should return field1 group a,b,c and field2 group x,g,u and field3 return 10,20,30,40,50,60

Comment: Do you require comma seperated values in column Field3 of group field1 and field2?

Comment: it does not matter as i can see all value in field3

Comment: See this link for values in one column x row:[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371914/how-to-get-multiple-column-data-in-a-comma-separated-string)

Comment: I need to see value return in column for field1, field2 and field3. Can we possible to do it or impossible?

Comment: @user1203397 yes, it's possible. Look at my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear. If i understand your question correctly, this is what you want right? You didn't mention to `SUM` up the values in Field3 or `MAX`, `MIN` or etc.

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Group_Concat(Field3)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Field1
```

Result:

```
Field1     Field2    Field3
a             x        10, 20 
b             g        30, 40
c             u        50, 60
```

**UPDATE**

as i read the comment, you want this query:

```
SELECT group_concat(Distinct Field1),
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Field2),
       GROUP_CONCAT(Field3)
FROM tableName;
```

will Result:

```
Field1     Field2    Field3
a,b,c      x,g,u       10, 20 , 30, 40, 50, 60
```

Comment: Try this but error on sql 2008 Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'group_concat' is not a recognized aggregate function. Please help agian

Comment: @user1203397 what server are you using? `group_concat` is available on MySQL and SQLite, other than that you have to create a function same with functionality of `Group_Concat`