# Send dbMail from SQL Server 2000 with Tabular structured data?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000, sp-send-dbmail, dbmail

I am trying to achieve this kind of formatted data from my select statement and have it send via database mail in SQL SERVER 2000. I know how to do this in SQL 2008.

```
Column1 | Column 2
------------------
Value 1 | Value 2
Value 1 | Value 2
Value 1 | Value 2
```

Comment: Actually comma separated list for multiple column would work as well with header. How can I do that , any pointers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized that this can not be done. To achieve this I created .bat file and stored procedures and sendmail utility.

First call this in your .bat file

> osql -S %ServerName%  -d %dbname% -U %username% -P %password% -Q "EXEC
>   "  -o %TempFile1%  -s "|"  -w 5000 >>%logfile%

and then call

> C:\Tools\SendEmail\sendEmail.exe -f  -t  -u
>   "[%ServerName%] Number of Records Processed: %lineCount%" -m "Data
>   File Generated: %DataFile%" -a %DataFile% -s